# Why are my java.net snapshots using Sonatype not appearing

Tags: maven, sonatype

My JAUDIOTAGGER project is hosted on java.net and can deploy new versions of my snapshot as follows

mvn deploy -Dgpg.passphrase=password

It all seems to work, this is the output I get:

```
Uploading: https://maven.java.net/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2//net/jthink/jaudiotagger/2.0.4/jaudiotagger-2.0.4.jar
892K uploaded (jaudiotagger-2.0.4.jar)
[INFO] Retrieving previous metadata from jvnet-nexus-staging
[INFO] Uploading repository metadata for: 'artifact net.jthink:jaudiotagger'
[INFO] Uploading project information for jaudiotagger 2.0.4
Uploading: https://maven.java.net/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2//net/jthink/jaudiotagger/2.0.4/jaudiotagger-2.0.4-sources.jar
875K uploaded (jaudiotagger-2.0.4-sources.jar)
Uploading: https://maven.java.net/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2//net/jthink/jaudiotagger/2.0.4/jaudiotagger-2.0.4-javadoc.jar
2317K uploaded (jaudiotagger-2.0.4-javadoc.jar)
Uploading: https://maven.java.net/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2//net/jthink/jaudiotagger/2.0.4/jaudiotagger-2.0.4.jar.asc
499b uploaded (jaudiotagger-2.0.4.jar.asc)
Uploading: https://maven.java.net/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2//net/jthink/jaudiotagger/2.0.4/jaudiotagger-2.0.4.pom.asc
499b uploaded (jaudiotagger-2.0.4.pom.asc)
Uploading: https://maven.java.net/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2//net/jthink/jaudiotagger/2.0.4/jaudiotagger-2.0.4-sources.jar.asc
499b uploaded (jaudiotagger-2.0.4-sources.jar.asc)
Uploading: https://maven.java.net/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2//net/jthink/jaudiotagger/2.0.4/jaudiotagger-2.0.4-javadoc.jar.asc
499b uploaded (jaudiotagger-2.0.4-javadoc.jar.asc)
```

However when I go to:

https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots/net/jthink/jaudiotagger/2.0.4-SNAPSHOT/

there is no change

If I go to

https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/net/jthink/jaudiotagger/2.0.4-SNAPSHOT/

then both these files are updated

- maven-metadata.xml.md5
- maven-metadata.xml.sha

but nothing else

I'm not clear which one it should be in , but shouldnt it be in at least one of these

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working.

I logged onto https://maven.java.net/index.html#welcome and deleted various staging repositories.
Then I edited my pom so that version said

```
 <version>2.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

rather than

```
 <version>2.0.4</version>
```

and reran

```
mvn deploy -Dgpg.passphrase=xxxx
```

Now its available at

https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots/net/jthink/jaudiotagger/2.0.4-SNAPSHOT/

So now Im going to try and do a proper release, I assume I set version back to

```
<version>2.0.4</version>
```

but I cant find anything in the documentation that tells me I should do this.

Answer (score 0):

You are not deploying a SNAPSHOT you are deploying releases which means your artifacts will be uploaded into the staging repository. This is indicated by the upload url:

https://maven.java.net/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/ne...

Furthermore i assume you have to acknowledge the artifacts in the staging repo and afterwards the artifacts will be synchronized into the release repository.

Comment: Thanks, how do I deploy a snapshot release then ?

Comment: Because Ive found my notes and I think Ive always deployed my snapshots like this, whereas used mvn release:prepare for actual releases